On a convex property in the proof of Jensen's inequality
I am reading a proof of Jensen's inequality (the measure theoretic form) in Measure Theory, Probability and Stochastic Processes in Le Gall's book. I know not much about convex functions except the definition, which I believe is not even given in the book, but reads something like (for $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ convex),$$\varphi(tx+(1-t)y)\leq t\varphi(x)+(1-t)\varphi(y),$$for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$ and $t\in[0,1]$.
Now, here's the theorem.

Theorem 4.3: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A,\mu)$ be a probability space and let $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_+$ be a convex function. Then for every $f\in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal A,\mu)$, $$\int_\Omega \varphi\circ f\, d\mu\geq\varphi\left(\int_\Omega f\, d\mu\right).$$ Proof: Set $$\mathcal E_\varphi=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2:\forall x\in\mathbb R,\varphi(x)\geq ax+b\}.$$ Then by elementary properties of convex functions, $$\varphi \left(x\right)=\sup_{\left(a{,}b\right)\in \mathcal E_{\varphi }}\left(ax+b\right).\tag1$$ ... ... ...

I do not understand $(1)$. Why is this true?

Since $\phi$ is convex, for any point $(z,\phi(z)) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, there exists an affine function $f_z(x)=a_zx+b_z$, such that the line $L_z$ which corresponds to $f_z$ (i.e. the graph of $f_z$) passes through $(z,\phi(z))$ and the graph of $\phi$ lies above $L_z$. In other words $\phi(x) \geq f_z(x)$, with equality holding only for $x=z$. Let $A=\{f_z: z\in \mathbb{R}\}$ be the set of all such affine functions. For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have that
$$\sup_{f_z\in A}f_z(x) \geq \phi(x),$$
because $f_x(x)=\phi(x)$ and
$$\sup_{f_z\in A}f_z(x) \leq \phi(x),$$
because each function $f_z$ lies below $\phi$.
Of course, $A$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the set $\mathcal{E}_{\phi}$ above and so the claim follows.
